# Wrong Result in SUM()

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

SQL Server 2000 - 4 tables, 3 columns each. Personal ID (COTA), User (Telegestionador), and an amount-of-work value.

Tables are: `Contactados, NC, FQ, OT`

Example of one of them.

```
XAV045  QUIPILDORY    26
XAV045  QUIPILDORY    29
XAV045  QUIPILDORY    21
XAV045  QUIPILDORY    39
XAV052  LOPEZRA       29
XAV052  LOPEZRA       39
XAV052  LOPEZRA       24
XAV052  LOPEZRA       36
```

What I need is. A result-view with ID, USER and then the fields with the sum of the amount of work grouped by personal id/user. (there are 4 tables, so in the final view I should have 6 columns)

So, first row should be

```
XAV045,QUIPILDORY, 115, X, Y, Z
```

Being X, Y, Z the results of `SUM()` from the other 3 tables.

First try is this:

```
SELECT     
   dbo.Contactados.COTA, dbo.Contactados.telegestionador, 
   SUM(dbo.Contactados.Total) AS Total, 
   SUM(dbo.OT.Total) AS [Cont-Der], 
   SUM(dbo.FQ.FQ) AS Cerrados, 
   SUM(dbo.NC.Total) AS NC
FROM
   dbo.Contactados 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   dbo.OT ON dbo.Contactados.COTA = dbo.OT.COTA AND dbo.Contactados.telegestionador = dbo.OT.telegestionador AND dbo.Contactados.FGfin = dbo.OT.FGfin 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   dbo.FQ ON dbo.Contactados.COTA = dbo.FQ.COTA AND dbo.Contactados.telegestionador = dbo.FQ.telegestionador AND dbo.Contactados.FGfin = dbo.FQ.FGfin 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   dbo.NC ON dbo.Contactados.COTA = dbo.NC.COTA AND dbo.Contactados.telegestionador = dbo.NC.telegestionador AND dbo.Contactados.FGfin = dbo.NC.FGfin
GROUP BY 
   dbo.Contactados.telegestionador, dbo.Contactados.COTA
```

It throws wrong results, I know `GROUP BY` groups the results, not the table rows individually. But I can't find the proper way to do so.

Any help?

Comment: You didn't mention FGfin in your question - could that be what's causing the problem with your own query result?

Comment: It wasn´t, it was just part of the prior tables but not included in the result. thanks.

Comment: Not sure what's wrong with your query, though, if anything. Could it be you needed: `SUM(dbo.FQ.TOTAL) AS Cerrados`? Or are there some COTA/telegestionador values that don't have Contactados records?

Comment: As Davis said, I'd need to use FULL OUTER JOINS, but he came up with a very good solution to the problem. Thanks Sean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that all four tables have identical datatypes for the four columns, you can use a union all to list all values, and then sum those as part of a subquery:

```
SELECT
COTA
,Telegestionador
,SUM(CASE WHEN table_name = 'Contactados' THEN work_value ELSE 0 END) AS Contactados_sum
,SUM(CASE WHEN table_name = 'NC' THEN work_value ELSE 0 END) AS nc_sum
,SUM(CASE WHEN table_name = 'FQ' THEN work_value ELSE 0 END) AS fq_sum
,SUM(CASE WHEN table_name = 'QT' THEN work_value ELSE 0 END) AS qt_sum
FROM
(
SELECT 
COTA
,Telegestionador
,work_value
,'Contactados' as table_name
FROM Contactados
UNION ALL
SELECT 
COTA
,Telegestionador
,work_value
,'NC' as table_name
FROM NC
UNION ALL
SELECT 
COTA
,Telegestionador
,work_value
,'FQ' as table_name
FROM FQ
UNION ALL
SELECT 
COTA
,Telegestionador
,work_value
,'QT' as table_name
FROM QT
) summary
GROUP BY
COTA
,Telegestionador
```

Comment: it's working nicely after trying this code. Thanks a lot. I haven't thought about a CASE, I was trying to SELECT inside the JOINs but this fix of yours is great.

Comment: The problem with joins is that you'd need a master list of all contacts to then left outer join to. The road you were going down would require FULL OUTER JOINS instead, which would add considerable overhead to the query!